# Suggest some journals that I can try to publish my paper in?

Tags: publishing

A little bit about myself: I'm in my senior year of high school, and I have a passion for majoring in math. Recently, I have written a paper that explores some consequences that result from FLT. 
My question is that I want to publish it somewhere, but I am not familiar with lists of journals. Because the results are pretty trivial, I assume it is meant for lower-end journals? It would be great if you can suggest me some.
Thank you for reading, here is the link to the paper: https://www.scribd.com/document/422435256/On-the-Rationality-and-Transcendentality-of-Solutions-to-the-Equation-x-n-y-n-z-n

Comment: Hummmm..... What is FLT?

Comment: @David I guess it's Fermat's last theorem,

Comment: @David Fermat's Last Theorem. The link tells you that.

Comment: FLT is Fermat’s last theorem

Comment: Nice job, but since the article is already freely available, isn't it already "published"? Can it be publisehd again at a journal? I would definitely cite you if I needed!

Comment: If you just want it published, why not go with arXiv.org?

Comment: I want it to be gone under peer-review to see how it goes. About arXiv, I really want to but unfortunately I don't have anyone to endorse me

Answer (score 0):

First, congratulations. I took a quick look at your paper. I think your characterization as "pretty trivial" is a little too modest, but not much. So you will probably not be able to publish in a widely read high quality journal.

I suggest you try some of the links at this search for [publish high school math research](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=publish%20high%20school%20math%20research&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)